# D3 animate donut chart while updating it with different data length

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, d3.js

I tried to find the answer on the internet but couldn't. I saw a lot of similar quations but not exactly what I need.

So, I have a donut chart with text labels. What I need is to update it with the new set of data. The problem is that new data is completely different.

Example. First set of data:

```
var data1 = [{key: 'label1', value: 3}, {key: 'label2', value: 5}];
```

and second data set is:

```
var data2 = [{key: 'label1', value: 25}];
```

So, the difference is in data array length. It can be different as I change data by clicking a button.

I used http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799 this example to build my donut and it woking propely when data changes with equal data length, but when data length is different animation dousn't work. It just reload itself.

Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: The example you linked to seems to work correctly when the length of the data array changes.  What are you doing differently?

Comment: Thank you. I tried to copy and change the data and haven't worked. But I tried to change domain data. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I copy directly the example and change the call and works

http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/JdWbME

```
var data1 = [{label: 'label1', value: 3}, {label: 'label2', value: 15}];
var data2 = [{label: 'label1', value: 25}];
change(data1);
```

I think your problem is the key of the hash 'label'

Comment: Thank you. I tried to copy and change the data and haven't worked. But I tried to change domain data. That was my mistake.

Comment: This mean? Did you change the key of the hash 'label'?

Comment: I coudn't make it work because I was trying to change data inside domain. d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data1). On click I was changing to ...domain(data2).